# Why are there two test fixtures for every fixture file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Fixture, (*.ylm) files by default have two fixtures, named `:one` and `:two`. Where is the second fixture, `:two` used. I can find `:one` in a file search but not `:two`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can rename it and use it in your tests. For a example `two:` can be replaced with something like `test_client:` as follows

```
test_client:
  category: Buisness
  status: Active
  first_name: John
  last_name: Doe
```

And then this can be used in model test as follow

```
def setup
  @client = clients(:test_client)
end

test "client should have a first_name" do
    @client.first_name = ""
    assert_not @client.save
end
```

Comment: If I look at my test database after testing, It has records for both `one:` and `two`, so their both used.